# What to do with all this money?

Tags: dnd-5e

I'm new to running a game with money in it (the last game I ran was Judge Dredd so it was't an issue), and one of my players turned to me while he was looting the Tresandor Manor and said "What am I going to do with all this money?"

While there are some obvious answers such as "buy new weapons and pay for meals", are there classic things to have people save for in a D&D setting? It seems that the average small encounter could easily uncover enough money to last a long time, and I don't fancy role playing an Independent Financial Advisor.

What I was thinking was trying to get the players to essentially fund the development of Phandelvar, meaning that they would need to return to the area every so often in order to see how things were progressing.